# Как привязать доменное имя к node.js?

Tags: node.js, сервер, домен

Я зарегистрировал простое доменное имя для тестирований на сайте dot.tk.

Пусть оно будет назваться mysite.tk.

Имею приложение под node.js для простоты типа "Hello World!"

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express()
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!')
});
server.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Port 3000!')
});
```

На локальном сервере всё работает. То есть на localhost:3000 выдаёт "Hello World".

**Вопрос: как мне связать мой новый домен mysite.tk и мой сервер на компьютере?**

Знаю, что вроде как по умолчанию при сопоставлении имени домена с IP-адресом весь трафик должен поступать на порт **80**. Не знаю, может в этом и проблема. Тут я просто использую другой порт: 3000.

Answer (score 2):

> Знаю, что вроде как по умолчанию при сопоставлении имени домена с
>   IP-адресом весь трафик должен поступать на порт 80

Это если порт не указывать. Можно явно указать порт mysite.tk:3000, тогда будет стучаться к нему.

Если вы хотите запускать сервис на 3000, но при этом, чтоб при обращении к домену без порта, запрос шёл к этому сервису, то нужно сервер конфигурировать. К примеру, в nginx есть `upstream`. Пример конфига:

```
upstream myupstream {
  keepalive 100;

  server localhost:3000;
}


server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.tk;

        keepalive_timeout 3600;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass          http://myupstream ;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
}
```

Осталось только для домена поменять `A` и `CNAME` DNS записи и настроить их на внешний ip вашего сервера.